# State variable doesn't get updated in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, parsing

Sample JSON:

```json
{
  "tutor_id": "1",
  "first_name": "Martin",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "grade": "Senior",
  "subject": "Integral Calculus",
  "subjects": [{ "subject_id": "2", "subject": "Linear Algebra" }]
}
```

My goal is to access `"subject":"Linear Algebra"` in the latter part of the JSON above. `tutorDetails.subjects` works but `tutorDetails.subjects[0]` returns an error that '0' is undefined.

[image: Error]

My Code:

```
import React, {useState, useMemo} from "react";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';
import axios from 'axios';

 function TutorCard({tutor_id, first_name, last_name, grade, subject}) {
    return (
        <div className="md:flex bg-white shadow text-gray-800 my-4 py-4 px-10 rounded-md items-center justify-between hover:bg-gray-300"  >
            {/* <img
                style={{ maxWidth: "60px"}}
                className="rounded-full shadow-md border border-gray-300"
                src={image}
                alt="employee"
            /> */}
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center"}}>{tutor_id}</p>
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center"}}>{first_name}</p>
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{last_name}</p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{grade}</p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{subject}</p>
            <AlertDialogSlide tutorID = {tutor_id} firstName = {first_name} lastName = {last_name} grade = {grade} subject = {subject} />
        </div>
    )
}




const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

function AlertDialogSlide(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const [tutorDetails, setTutorDetails] = useState([ ])

components (componentDidMount, componentWillMount)
    useMemo( () => {
    const retrieveData = async () => {
        const resp = await axios.get('API call' + props.tutorID);
        console.log("Tutor Info Response: " + JSON.stringify(resp.data));
        console.log("AltSubjects: " + JSON.stringify(resp.data.subjects[0]));
        setTutorDetails(resp.data);

    }

    retrieveData();
}, []);

    

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        {'>'}
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
        fullWidth = {true}
      >
        <DialogTitle>{props.firstName + " " + props.lastName}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText >
            <strong>Level: </strong> {props.grade} <br/>
            <strong>Subject: </strong> {props.subject} <br/>
            {/* <div> {(tutorDetails.subjects).map(sub => <div>  <strong>Alternative Subject: </strong> {JSON.stringify(sub)} <br/> </div>)} </div> */}
            <strong>Alternative Subject: </strong> {tutorDetails.subjects[0]} <br/>
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
export default TutorCard;
```

I tried researching through other resources but, nothing has helped so far.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: Also, why are you declaring a const function and then calling it when the code's already wrapped in a function wrapper? Just... run that code?

Comment: Also also, you don't need `JSON.stringify()`, just `tutorDetails.subjects[0].subject`

Comment: Given your edit: [show your code](/help/how-to-ask). If the error is on `tutorDetails` then show your actual ([mcve] of course) entire component, where you should what `tutorDetails` even is. The error currently says that `tutorDetails` has no property called `subjects`. Which would make sense, since you're using `useMemo` but you're not actually saving that memoized function and then using it (from what you're showing)

Comment: Your code involves an asynchronous operation. The `tutorDetails` content will not be available until the axios call completes.

Comment: @Pointy I see. So, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`tutorDetails` has an initial value of `[]` when the component mounts (*initial render*), so when you are trying to access `tutorDetails.subjects[0]` is expectedly throwing an error "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')*".

Instead make sure the data is received before you're trying to access anything from it by conditionally rendering; and looking at your data sample you'd wanna access `subject` property from the `tutorDetails.subjects[0]` Object (since React can't render Objects):

```html
<strong>Alternative Subject: </strong> {tutorDetails.subjects !== undefined && tutorDetails.subjects[0].subject} <br/>
```